# Multiple EF Models in a single assembly

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4

Using EF 4.0 i'm trying to do what i think should be dead simple but it seems to be generating broken code.

1. Create a new project (class library)
2. add a new EF model and generate from a db (doesn't matter what)
3. Compile (all good)
4. add a 2nd EF model and generate from a db (again, doesn't matter what)
5. Compile (breaks)

Can you only have a single EF model per assembly or something?

I'm not aware of any limitation ... although it seems to put code in that breaks everything as soon as you add a second model.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Ok i got round the problem by adding each EF model to a sub folder this generates the duplicate code still but puts it in a separate namespace ... u'd think it would be smart enough to figure out the duplication ... oh well.

Comment: "breaks" isn't a particularly helpful error report.

Comment: yeh thats why i posted the steps to reproduce the problem ... looking through the code generated and the errors in question it seems to generate identical code in both EF model code behind files. Then generate a sub namespace with the entities in it ...

Comment: I've just got round to trying this, and it all works fine. Because all the classes EF generates are `partial`, there can be multiple definitions of classes with the same fully qualified name. What are the actual compile errors you get, in a minimal reproduction case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never did completely get to the bottom of this but I figured out a work around which was to basically delete the project file and recreate it.

Odd that it would affect EF like this though??